# How to SELECT only numeral fields and only text field via console SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, console

I have the table`players` which consist of three columns;

First : `playerID` : `1,2,3`;

Second : `playerTeam` : `Honda,Ferrari,Mercedes`;

Third : `Age` : `22,29,31`;

I need two write to queries.

First : print ( SELECT ) all numeral fields from the table `players`.

Second : print ( SELECT ) all text fields from the table `players`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the select statements the way you describe it:

```
SELECT playerID, Age FROM players;
SELECT playerTeam FROM players;
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** 
if u want to select the only numeral from the column, u can do this

```
 SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE Isnumeric(column1);
```

**Second** 
for select only text field

```
SELECT usr_user_id FROM user WHERE usr_user_id REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help for collect the columns from database using datatype filter. Try this.

```
declare @stringcolumns nvarchar(4000)
declare @numbercolumns nvarchar(4000)

select @stringcolumns= 
    'select '+ stuff((select ','+name from sys.all_columns where object_id=object_id('players')
  and type_name(user_type_id) in ('varchar','nvarchar','char','nvarchar')
    for   xml path('')),1,1,'') + ' from players'

select @numbercolumns= 
   'select ' +  stuff((select ','+name from sys.all_columns where object_id=object_id('players')
  and type_name(user_type_id) in ('numeric','int')
    for   xml path('')),1,1,'') +' from players'

execute sp_executesql @stringcolumns
execute sp_executesql @numbercolumns
```

---

To change the data type as your requirement in the following Code section

---

```
type_name(user_type_id)  in ('varchar','nvarchar','char','nvarchar')
```